# Script or Library to find contact means on a website

Tags: information-retrieval

Does anyone know a script/recipe/library to find most relevant contact information on a website?

Some possible case:

- Find contact phone number on a personal web page
- Find owner email address on a  blog
- Find url of the contact page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any libraries that do this.

Hm, I would use regular expressions to match for phone numbers and email addresses, combined with a web spider that walks the site, and then a method for ranking the contact information.

Typically contact information will also be partnered with one of a few common labels such as "Support", "Support email", "Sales", etc. There's probably a dozen or so versions of this that will cover 95% of all sites in English.

So, basically I would start by building a simple recursive web spider that walks all the publicly accessible pages in a given domain, parsing the HTML for email addresses and phone numbers, and making a list of them, and then ranking them based on whether or not they are listed near to any of the common labels.

It won't be perfect, but then again, that's part of the value of the algorithm - making it smarter, and tweaking it over time until it gets better.

Comment: I feel bad. I would have awarded you the bounty but I checked my email after it was automatically given. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [WSO2's Mashup Server](http://wso2.org/library/mashup-server). You can run it on your local machine and follow the tutorial for [scraping](http://wso2.org/project/mashup/2.3.0/docs/scraperhostobject.html). You could pass the dynamic parameters you need into the `<http>` element of the scraper to loop through multiple sites running the same scrape, then push everything to a collection source (AJAX application for capturing the information or store inside WSO2 server). You can write very complex search patterns using XPath and XSLT to capture the information you want.

I don't have enough information about the specific sites you are scraping to help with the script, but any way you go, it's going to take a lot of trial and error until you get the result you are looking for.

Happy scraping!